# A question based on maximum modulus principle

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

This question is part of my assignment on complex analysis course and I was unable to solve it.

> Find maximum and minimum values of $|\frac{z-\alpha}{1-\bar{\alpha} z} | $  on $|z|\leq 1$ . ( where $\alpha$ is such that |$\alpha$ |<1 and $\alpha$ is fixed.)

By maximum and minimum modulus principle it is clear that Maximum and minimum will be at |z|=1.

But I have no idea on how to find such valuevalues due to the complicated nature of function f.

So, it's my humble request to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the minimum is $0$, which is taken when $z=\alpha$.

On the other hand, if $|z|=1$, then$$\left|1-\overline\alpha z\right|=\left|\overline zz-\overline\alpha z\right|=\left|\overline z-\overline\alpha\right||z|=|z-\alpha|$$and therefore$$\left|\frac{z-\alpha}{1-\overline\alpha z}\right|=1$$and therefore the maximum is $1$.

Comment: why minimum is not on |z|=1?, is it due to the fact that Denominator of f can be 0 at z=$\alpha$ , so conditions of minimum modulus theorem are not satisfied

Comment: The minimum modulus theorem states that if an analytic functions has no zeros, the the minimum is attained at the boundary. But the function given here has a zero at $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

The map given by $f(z)=\frac{z-\alpha}{1-\overline{\alpha}z}$ for $|\alpha|<1$ is an automorphism of unit disc i.e.  f maps unit disc onto unit disc, therefore, $|f(z)|=1$ for all $|z|=1$.
You can use the following link to read a detailed discussion:
[Automorphisms of the unit disk](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1367282/automorphisms-of-the-unit-disk)